# PHP or jq code for opening multiple links in new tab but in only one tab

Tags: php

I have site in php and and i have multiple links to open in new tab (by using _blank). But i want to that all links will in only one tab. So i open first links it open in new tab and clicked on second link it will open in same tab where first link currently open. So it is possible, If yes then how?

Comment: _PHP or jq code for..._ PHP does'nt have anything to do with that--- what about window.open():

Comment: as i understood clearly ? you mean when you  open first link it will open in new tab so when you open second  link second link has to open above the first link?

Comment: Yes means second links will be in same tab where first links open. Means that second links replaced at first links in that tab.

Comment: so by that time first link will hide right?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a page in tab 0.  If you click on a link, you want it to open in tab 1.  If you click on any other link, it should open in tab 1 as well.  Did I get this?  The only option in HTML is `_blank`, or nothing.  I used to code my sites with "_blank", because I liked it.  Then I started reading (like https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95651/when-to-open-link-in-new-tab or https://medium.com/the-metric/links-should-open-in-the-same-window-447da3ae59ba) and I do not anymore.  Let the user decide how to user your site.

Comment: @suresh Yes right.. Right now when i'm open two links it is opening in two different tab. But i want only one tab.

Comment: @Nic3500 yes i want every new links in tab 1 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `target="_blank"`, you can choose a name and all links with that same name will go to the same tab. For example:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="my-tab">Link 1</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/" target="my-tab">Link 2</a>
```